# pip does not log to file (using config option)

Tags: python, pip

I edited the pip user config to log to a file using `pip config set user.log ~/pip.log` but it never writes to that file.
When I run pip with the `--log ~/pip.log` option it works though.

The output of the `pip config debug`:

```
env_var:
env:
global:
  /etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
  /etc/pip.conf, exists: False
site:
  /home/user/python/venv/speech/pip.conf, exists: False
user:
  /home/user/.pip/pip.conf, exists: False
  /home/user/.config/pip/pip.conf, exists: True
    user.log: /home/user/pip.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be in section `[global]` in the config file. So unset it and set properly:

```
pip config unset user.log
pip config set global.log ~/pip.log
```